# How can i get user avatar using api in ejabbred?

Tags: php, ejabberd-api

I need to get a user profile image OR avatar using an API from *EJABBRED* ?
I am using PHP for API.
How can i accomplish that?

Comment: Please add more details to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you store the avatar, as there are several ways in Jabber. For example, Tkabber can store the avatar in the user vcard. In this case, you can use the get_vcard2 command. For example:

> $ ejabberdctl get_vcard2 user1 localhost PHOTO BINVAL
>   R0lGODdhcAAcAIABAAAAAP///ywAAAAAcAAcAAACb4SPqcvtD6OctNqLadi8+w+G4kiW5skh6Mq27pse8EzXrWrn+h7g/A9c+YLE4mdoTBKRyuaO6YzSoNLqTWbNvqjarojrDXfAYjG57D2jteq1te2WwuPOOV1pvxvz+iW2H8YH+JNRaHiImKi4yAhQAAA7